# String variable may not have been initialized (error diects to line 34)

Tags: java, string, initialization

I've been trying to get the string initialize, but to no avail.  I have tried all of the solutions I have come across and I am not sure whether it is because of my ineptness or because I need a new solution I already have the logic of the program worked out, so I just need help trying to initialize the string value.  If anyone could help, I would be much obliged!

P.S  Curse me for wanting a challenge and using srings.  -_-

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RockPaperScissors
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String player, computer;
    int answer;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    Random generator = new Random();
    answer = generator.nextInt(3) + 1;

    if (answer < 1 || answer > 3)
            answer = generator.nextInt(3) + 1;

    if (answer == 1)
        computer = "rock";
    if (answer == 2)
        computer = "paper";
    if (answer == 3)
        computer = "scissors";

    System.out.println ("Please choose rock, paper, or scissors.");
    player = scan.nextLine();

    if (!player.equalsIgnoreCase("rock") || !player.equalsIgnoreCase("paper") 
            || !player.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors"))
    {
        System.out.println ("Please correctly enter one of the three 
                    choices: rock, paper, and scissors.");
        player = scan.nextLine();
    }

    if (player.compareTo(computer) == 0)
        System.out.println ("It's a draw!  You both chose " + player + 
                    "!");

    if ((computer.equalsIgnoreCase("rock") &&  
            player.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")) && 
            (computer.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors") && player.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")) 
            && (computer.equalsIgnoreCase("paper") && player.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")))
        System.out.println ("You lost!  The computer chose " + computer + " 
                    and you chose " + player + ".");

    if ((player.equalsIgnoreCase("rock") &&  
            computer.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")) && 
            (player.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors") && 
            computer.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")) && 
            (player.equalsIgnoreCase("paper") &&     
            computer.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")))
            System.out.println ("You won!  CONGRATULATIONS!  The computer chose             
                    " + computer + " and you chose " + player + ".");

}
```

}

Comment: So, set your string variables to "" when you declare them.

Answer (score 1):

```
String computer; // not initialized
```

change this to

```
String computer = null;  or ""// initialized
if (player.compareTo(computer) == 0)
```

because, the variable computer will assigned based on the condition. If the above condition you mentioned is not satisfied. The value is none, so only it show the error.

Answer (score 1):

The compilator see you have String computer. He can also see that this computer is initialized for answer 1 or 2 or 3. But because it cant read logic, it does not know anything about if answer can be or cannot be lower or higher so it is assuming the worst possibility - that computer will not be initialized.

Just change your up line to

```
String computer = "";
```

and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question at all, than keep in mind you can't do this in Java:

```
String str = "here is some
    random text";
```

What you can do is

```
String str = "here is some " + 
    "random text";
```

In other words - can't break a string at the end of the line, gotta close it and use a `+` sign.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the values of `Strings` in two ways:

```
String abc = "I love basketball";
```

or

```
String abc = new String("I love basketball");
```

What you are seeing is a warning and not an error. If you insist on not putting a value into the `String`, just do

```
String abc = null;
```

or

```
String abc = ""
```

In the latter case, your String is initialized to the characters between the quotations. Nothing, basically, but it is not `null`.

To avoid potential `NPE` problems, compare the `String`s as follows:

```
"rock".equalsIgnoreCase(playerChoice);
```